# Reference for own site in question.

Tags: discussion, editing

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2212115/59234), the user mentions a "source" for the problem. After going to his profile, I realized that this source is (may be?) the user's own website. Note however that such a source is not *linked* in the question, it is only mentioned. Note also that the source does not improve the post or clarify it in any way.

I feel this can be understood as self-advertising, but the situation is not so clear (particularly because of the lack of a link in the question itself). I've thought of editing that away, but I don't know if this is proper. So, my question is: Should we intervene or let it be?

EDIT: Just to clarify, the site being in the profile is not something which is an issue at all, in my opinion. I just mentioned it as being an evidence that the site mentioned is indeed of ownership of the user

EDIT 2: May be relevant to say that more than 10 questions by the user (out of 17) have that same reference, ipsis litteris.

Comment: Note that the user in question also posted https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28205/my-job-is-to-write-mathematics-enigmas-can-i-use-mse

Comment: In so far as there seems to be no commercial solicitation or inducement in the Question itself, I don't see a problem with how the user presents him- or herself as the source of the problem.  The profile is appropriately used to list contact information, such as "the user's own website," and my feeling is that it would be okay to do so even where it is hoped contacts might result in business transactions away from Math.SE.

Comment: Giving one's own site as a reference is harmless if the reference does add some context and valuable information to the post. I have given references to my blog and the posts therein in my profile as well as in many answers. The purpose is only to give more details which may not fit in an answer. In one case the asker responded that I put some long proof from blog in the answer and I obliged.

Comment: As you can see from the linked Meta post, this user merely wants to challenge others here rather than contribute directly to Math SE as a repository. The SE system does encourages self-answering if one wishes to share useful knowledge. But not only is this user posting puzzle-like questions (admitting they are about 'finding the trick'), he/she also does not post an answer to it. I find this unacceptable. Others may differ.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Also see [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/64511/2017/8/27) and [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/57121?m=43699858#43699858) and [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/36?m=43522502#43522502) and [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?user=261245&q=EC).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I agree that a reference which provides some context and/or value and/or additional information which is relevant to the question is harmless, and even useful. I don't think this particular reference does any of that.

Comment: Oh yes that question you have linked has many issues apart from including a not so useful reference. And therefore has been rightly put on hold.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think this is a problem unless the user is doing it all the time. An occasional reference to some work the user has written outside of StackExchange isn't self-promotion if done honestly. Many professors reference their websites for expository articles or lists of open problems, which doesn't seem to me to be qualitatively different from whatever "enigmas" are.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't think the parallel with professors referencing their website is proper. This is usually done in the profile page (see my edit), or in an answer when it provides some additional information which is relevant to the question. I don't think this applies here. Moreover, there is a difference between an academic webpage and a website which seems a personal endeavor of sorts (which even contains ads on it, so there may be monetary interest).